# Read XML File Using Linq is not reading element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am not able to get the value from this xml response, I will appreciate any help.

```
<Response>
  <Result>
    <Item1>GREEN</Item1>
    <Item2>05/19/2017 22:08:14</Item2>
  </Result>
  <Other>
    <Id>xxxxxxxxxxxxc</Id>
  </Other>
</Response>
```

What I tried so far but the results is empty

```
string responseXml = response.ToXML();
XElement doc = XElement.Load(new StringReader(responseXml));
var results = from p in
              doc.Descendants("Result")
              select new
              {
                  item = p.Element("Item1").Value,
              };

foreach (var elm in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elm.item);
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. As you can see in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GUoRdE), if you run your code substituting `reponseXml` for the XML in the question, the output is `GREEN` - your code works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parse instead of load.  You may also be getting error due to extra characters in the string.  In the string you postged there are single quotes.  Not sure if the single quote is in the actual string you are using.

```
            string responseXml = "<Response>" +
                               "<Result>" +
                                 "<Item1>GREEN</Item1>" +
                                 "<Item2>05/19/2017 22:08:14</Item2>" +
                               "</Result>" +
                               "<Other>" +
                                 "<Id>xxxxxxxxxxxxc</Id>" +
                               "</Other>" +
                             "</Response>";
            XElement doc = XElement.Parse(responseXml);
            var results = from p in
                              doc.Descendants("Result")
                          select new
                          {
                              item = p.Element("Item1").Value,
                          };

            foreach (var elm in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(elm.item);
            }
```